# Response Processing In Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

step1: Jmeter send request to Server 
step2: Server Will send Response in decrypted form to Jmeter. 
 Now Here My Task start.
step3 : Now I need to perform some logic to decrypted response.

But Not getting where put to my logic of response handling.

What I have tried till now.
1. I extracted ApacheJmeterhttp.jar and put logic in HttpSamplerProxy Class inside sample method. and made jar with specified changes. It worked fine. But i dont want to change in internal jar file.

1. I made a class and extended AbstractFuntion class. Write logic inside overrided execute method. And Used PostProcessor to execute it. It worked. But it is a syncronized method. Takes time for each response handling. Means Handle each response sequentially not parallel. And Requirment is handling response parallel. So its not convenient for me

Please suggest me a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jsr223 Post Processor + Groovy as scripting language and finally ensure you use a cache key in JSR223 Post Processor configuration.

[image]

Comment: used this link [link]http://code4reference.com/2013/06/jmeter-custom-function-implementation/ for Making Custom function and Put decryted logic inside syncronised execute method according to above URL.

Comment: Above Post helped me. Thanks for giving suitable answer.  I put logic inside JSR223 PostProcessor script area, Its working fine. I am beginner in jmeter So give me sample of Groovy Script or provide me link for groovy script. And not able to understand  this line "finally ensure you use a cache key in JSR223 Post Processor configuration".

Comment: 'code'(import com.jacob.activeX.*;
import com.jacob.com.*;

ActiveXComponent comp = new ActiveXComponent("Com.Calculation");
String str = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
String decryptData=Dispatch.call(comp, "uncompress",str).toString();
byte[] modifiedResponse = decryptData.getBytes();
prev.setResponseData(modifiedResponse);)

Comment: In above comment i have to declare comp as a static variable but not able to do that. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You should accept this answer as it seems fine. Then ask another question about this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Code Inside Execute Method

```
public synchronized String execute(SampleResult previousResult, Sampler currentSampler)throws InvalidVariableException {
log.info("@ Inside execute");
String decryptData=Dispatch.call(comp, "uncompress", str).toString();
byte[] orignalResponse = previousResult.getResponseData();
byte[] addedData = decryptData.getBytes();
orignalResponse = ArrayUtils.addAll(orignalResponse, addedData);
previousResult.setResponseData(orignalResponse);
return "";
}
```